# Parameters must be considered while sorting an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I want to join multiple sorting algorithms like, selection sort, insertion sort, bubble sort, quick sort, merge sort, etc on a given array by drawing some patterns from the data.

To put it more simply, I would like to split the array into multiple parts and send each part to a sorting algorithm based on the identified pattern in the data. Then merge all the sorted arrays using the merge concept of the merge sort algorithm.

For splitting the data, I am comparing the values of the current element with the previous element and making a decision solely based on this.

**Example:** Input Array - [10, 11, 12, 13, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1]
I am breaking this array into 3 parts - [10, 11, 12, 13], [7, 8, 9], [3, 2, 1]

The logic behind breaking this array into multiple arrays is pretty simple. I am just identifying a number that is breaking the pattern.
In the above example, till 13, the array is increasing but 7 is less than 13.
The same case with the last array too! 3 is less than 9 and so I am considering that as a decreasing array.

I want to what are the different kinds of arrays we can find while sorting an array of data. Types I know are Increasing Array, Decreasing Array, and an Unknown Array.

Unknown Array: If we add 15 at the last to the above example, as we don't have any value to compare 15 with, I am classifying this as an Unknown as of now.

Also, what parameters I should consider while sending a sub-array to a specific algorithm.
I am currently analyzing whether standard deviation plays any role in selecting a sorting algorithm.

All suggestions are welcome!

Thank you

Comment: I suggest posting your coding attempts at solving this interesting problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Sorry, I have not yet started any coding for this topic. It is still on the paper. I'm looking for a few parameters to start.

Comment: Also look at Timsort for some inspiration

Comment: Why would adding `15` make it an unknown array? After `[3,2,1]`, you can have `[15]` as an already "sorted" element

Comment: @AbhinavMathur
Yes, that's actually my next step after splitting the array into sub-array. Now, I am looking for the best algorithm that sorts multiple increasing subarrays.
As I can split the array into multiple subarrays, I can convert a decreasing array into an increasing array just by reversing the list.